# Mixture, linear combination, and bivariate distributions how do they differ?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I would like to better understand the difference between these three distributions of random variables/vectors. To make this easier to talk about:

Let $X_1$ be a random variable with $N(0,1)$ distribution.

Let $X_2$ be a random variable with $\chi^2(r)$ distribution.

Consider:

1. The distribution of the random vector $X=(X_1, X_2)^T$
2. The distribution of the random variable $Y=X_1+ X_2$
3. The random variable Z defined as the mixture of $X_1, X_2$ with pdf $f_{X}(x)=\frac 12 f_{X_1}(x_1)+\frac 12 f_{X_2}(x_2)$

No two of these are the same distribution. But, could I make modifications so they would be the same?

Comment: From $X$ you can obtain $Y$ by adding its components (obviously). $Z$ is not determined by $X$, but you can get a random variable with the same distribution as $Z$ if you flip a fair coin and choose one of the components of $X$.

Comment: Note: the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ also depends on whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Comment: "From XX you can obtain YY by adding its components (obviously)." This is obvious in retrospect, but it cleared up a bunch of the fogginess I've had about this concept, thanks.

Comment: So can I get from Y to Z?